# How to change the list of values in a ComboBox depending on the value selected in another ComboBox in VB6?

Tags: combobox, vb6

I am doing a VB6 project on Hotel Booking System.
I want to load a ComboBox named RoomNumber according to the selected value in the ComboBox named HotelNumber.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us your current approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code in the HotelNumber_Click event. There you can load something in the RoomNumber ComboBox like this:

```
RoomNumber.AddItem HotelNumber.List(HotelNumber.ListIndex)
```

This will just copy the data from one ComboBox to the other but you can do any other task you want since you haven't specified what exactly you want to do.